# Attempting to upgrade pip from version 20.3.1 to version 21.3. How do I use the `--user` option?

Tags: python, pip, upgrade

For the sake of experience, I'd prefer to try this in cmd and not use get-pip in pypi.org

Tried changing windows account from user to administrator and a youtube instruction video.

Was awarded the following error message:

Successfully uninstalled pip-20.3.1

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-j78tgiwv\pip.exe'

Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Comment: Run `cmd` as Administrator. This does not involve changing the account. It is simply a matter of elevating your permissions. (Though in a corporate environment you might not be allowed to do that.) In  Search bottom left  type `cmd` then choose the option Run as Administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `pip install --upgrade --user pip` (like `pip` is suggesting) will install `pip` on the user site packages (not the global). This works fine on some cases, but the upgraded package will only be available to the user who installed.

As I can read, your message seems harmless (it failed on a temporary file), if you run `pip --version` you should see the latest version. However, if that doesn't work, you may have to add the `--user` option to your command.

Comment: It worked: `C:\Users\User> pip --version
pip 21.3 from c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)` Thanx